# How to access a docker container on linux box from any computer on the network

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, docker, containers

I have a docker container hosted on a linux box.I need to access it from any computer on my local network.

From the answer obtained from this question ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083546/docker-macvlan-network-unable-to-access-internet , I was able to give the container an ip address that is on 10.30.21.* subnet.

My linux box and other computers on my network are on 10.30.20.* subnet .At the moment , I can ping my linux box (host) , 8.8.8.8 and any other computer from the  docker container.

I can also ping the container and any other computer on my network from the host.

How do I ping the container from any other computer on the network?
I am new to docker.Thank you.

Comment: Did you setup a macvlan network in docker?  Is your docker host able to go into promiscuous mode?  Did you connect your container to the macvlan network you created?  Can you maybe update your question showing what you attempted to setup?  That would probably give us a better starting point to know what is going on and help you.

Comment: @Zoredache I tried setting up the container on a macvlan network on the host however I couldn't access any computer on the network or the host (not being able to access host is expected).The host is already in promiscuous mode.When I connect the container to the macvlan network,I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or any computer on my network.

Comment: The bridge network as explained on the link in the question allows me to ping my host, 8.8.8.8 and any computer on my subnet 10.30.20.*.@Zoredache